# left join linq when right list is empty

Tags: c#, linq

```
pdlist = (from a in context.EMPLOYEES
          join b in context.PERSONS on a.PERSON_ID equals b.PERSON_ID
          where a.SUPERVISOR_ID == empId
          select new Pollidut.Models.Pollidut
          {
              PollidutId = a.EMPLOYEE_ID,
              PollidutName = b.PERSON_NAME,
              DistributionHouseId = a.DISTRIBUTION_HOUSE_ID == null ? 0 : (int)a.DISTRIBUTION_HOUSE_ID
          }).ToList();
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.Date;

var pdTargets = (from p in context.PALLYDUT_TARGET
                 where p.Active == true && p.StartDate <= dt && p.EndDate >= dt
                 group p by p.PallydutId into g
                 select new
                 {
                     PollidutId = g.Key,
                     Start = g.Select(x => x.StartDate).Min(),
                     End = g.Select(y => y.EndDate).Max(),
                     Target = g.Select(z => z.Target).Sum()
                 }).ToList();

var PdTargetsList = (from m in pdlist
                     join n in pdTargets on m.PollidutId equals n.PollidutId into t
                     from l in t.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     select new
                     {
                          PallydutId = m.PollidutId,
                          PallydutName = m.PollidutName,
                          DistributionId = m.DistributionHouseId,
                          StartDate = l.Start == null ? dt : l.Start,
                          EndDate = l.End == null ? dt : l.End,
                          Target = l.Target == null ? 0 : l.Target
                     }).ToList();
```

`pdlist` is employee list where pdTarget may set or not. `pdTarget` can be empty. When I left join pdlist with pdTargets I get Object reference not set error. pdTargets collection returns null.How to fix it. Anybody helps me greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason I suspect why you are getting a `Null reference exception` is because your are directly accessing the properties on a null object (`l` in your case), even though you are using a `DefaultIfEmpty()` method which is going to return null if no matching rows are found. You should change your code like this:-

```
 select new
        {
           PallydutId = m.PollidutId,
           PallydutName = m.PollidutName,
           DistributionId = m.DistributionHouseId,
           StartDate = l == null ? dt : l.Start,
           EndDate = l == null ? dt : l.End,
           Target = l == null ? 0 : l.Target
        }).ToList();
```

Also, If you think that your one object `pdTarget` can be null, then I don't think its about a left join or a normal join, your code will throw an exception in either case. Please check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882535.aspx) MSDN documentation to handle nulls in query expressions.